# searching Threshold Algorithm

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, threshold

I am currently working on a project. I have to separate the elements of the images I have got. On the first image you see the histogram of one of them. I want to calculate the threshold but I can't find a method of calculating the threshold that allows me to have a threshold that is around 135 (which is the threshold that is more or less perfect but I don't want to use a fixed threshold). This histogram is made on the green channel because it's easier to identify those colours on it (Any other idea is welcome). And the second image is an example of a recieved image.
[image]
[image]

Thank you in Advance

Comment: so you need to segment the pale from the pink areas?

Comment: I think this would benefit from a masking operation. select all pixels that aren't black, stick them in one array (row or column vector). use numpy for that. then run some automatic threshold (otsu?) on that... to get the *threshold* value, that you then apply to the *original* image in another (fixed) threshold.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz How can I do this? The default value in an array is 0 so even if I copy I will still have the black side. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: sketch: `mask = (im != 0).any(axis=2); selection = im[mask]; (the_threshold, _) = cv.threshold(selection, ...); thresholded = cv.threshold(im, the_threshold, ...)`

Comment: @cedrik24 How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

1. first of all we want to eliminate the black, so using the histogram we get the total count of pixels from 0 to 50 (for example) = `DarkPixelsCount`
2. then we start Counting pixels starting from 255 and accumulating the total number = `LighPixelsCount`
3. starting from 255 we will check
   `if (LighPixelsCount >= (90% of (TotalPixelsCount - DarkPixelsCount))` when this condition has been fulfilled then this is a good Threshold point.

Note: the fixed numbers I chose are for example you can expierment to get best results

**Option 2:**

1. Use Gamma Correction with very high value (for example 6.99 )
2. then chose a high threshold (for example 213)

the result

[image: Option 2 Result]